# Node Js : Multiple routes in single router file

Tags: node.js, express

Can we define multiple routes in single router file.
e.g : Consider we have company and user tab and I want to define 1 routers file for each tab. All Company related calls should be handled by Company router and User related calls should be handled by User router.

```
//app.js
app.use('/', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/api/user/load_user_list', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/api/user/get_user_detail', require('./routes/user'));

//User.js router
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//router 1
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here - 
});

//router 2
router.get('/api/user/load_user_list', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});

//router 3
router.get('/api/user/get_user_detail', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});
module.exports = router;
```

Currently, when app receives call for '/api/user/load_user_list' my "router 1" gets called.

Am I missing out something. To deal with this, I guess I can have single router call and delegate to different function based on request baseUrl.

Any help / suggestion will be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: I have a slight recollection that express will use "first match", you should list more specific routes before less specific, i.e. place route 1 last

Comment: I placed first route in the end but still "route 1" is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/api/user/load_user_list', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/api/user/get_user_detail', require('./routes/user'));
```

Just use :

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/user'))
app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/user'));
```

And in your router file rename the routes like so :

```
//router 2
router.get('/load_user_list', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});

//router 3
router.get('/get_user_detail', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});
```

Reason : 
When app.use('/api/user/xyz', require('./xyz')) is called, the uri path after api/user/xyz is sent to the router to be matched

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is, since you have given `/api/user/load_user_list` in  `app.use('/api/user/load_user_list', require('./routes/user'));`, **express will prefix** all the routes inside your `./routes/user` with `/api/user/load_user_list`.

The `/` **router 1** in your `user.js` becomes `/api/user/load_user_list` + `/` and `/api/user/load_user_list` in your `user.js` becomes `/api/user/load_user_list`(from app.js) + `/api/user/load_user_list`.

So only when you hit `/api/user/load_user_list/api/user/load_user_list`, your **router 2** will be called.

You can change your app.js code to

`app.use('/api/user', require('./routes/user'));`

and your `routes/user.js` to

```
//router 1
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here - 
});

//router 2
router.get('/load_user_list', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});

//router 3
router.get('/get_user_detail', function (req, res, next) {
    //do something here
});
```

Now, when you hit `/api/user/load_user_list`, it will match `/api/user`(app.js) + `/load_user_list`(routes/user.js) and the route which you wanted will be called.